# Text field auto complete with previous searches

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

I have a text field that is used for searches and I am trying to add functionality to show the user previous searches that have been entered as they type.  I want it to function similar to how the jQuery autocomplete works with a list displayed below the text box.  I was wondering if there is an HTML option built in that I can enable to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe there is an html solution. However some browsers do this automatically. At I know firefox does. Your best bet would be to store user's previous searches in localstorage or cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a five minutes try. Using cookie to store searches ([here's the code and the demo](http://jsbin.com/qulomiyuyi/2/edit?html,output)):

I have used the code of [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) demo at jQueryUI documentation page, and replaced the original array with series of cvs separated value (in a second moment splitted by comma) to recreate array.

```
// this func return cookie of name 'cname'
// if you use _searches as prameter you'll get a csv (i.e.: valeu1,value2...) containing the words searched
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

// this function adds value to '_searches' cookie
function search() {
  var s = getCookie('_searches');
  document.cookie = "_searches="+s+','+$("#search").val();
}
```

The magic happens here, where you tansform a csv in array suitable for jQueryUI autocomplete:

```
var availableTags = getCookie('_searches').split(',');
```

This is a five minutes try and need a lot of improvements, by the way this works.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var _source = [];
    $("#dynsearch")
    .autocomplete({
        // update `source` with `value` of `#dynsearch` ,
        // on `change` event
        change: function (event, ui) {
            // insert `#dynsearch` `value` into `_search` (`source`) array
            _source.splice(0, 0, event.target.value);
            event.target.value = "";
        },
        source: _source
    });
});
```

```js
$(function () {
    var _source = [];
    $("#dynsearch")
    .autocomplete({
        change: function (event, ui) {
            _source.splice(0, 0, event.target.value);
            event.target.value = "";
        },
        source: _source
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="dynsearch">search:</label>
    <input id="dynsearch" />
</div>
```